# Python3 - Permutations for 7 digit number that totals to a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I need to find a solution for the below problem in Python3. I tried `itertools.combinations` but not clear on how to do it.

Prepare a 7-digit number that sums to 5. Each digit can be between 0-4 only. Also, there can be repetitions. Valid example numbers are -

```
[ [2,1,1,0,0,1,0], [3,0,1,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,4,0,0,1], [1,0,0,3,0,1,0], [1,1,1,1,0,1,0], ...... ]
```

As you can see, numbers may appear more than once in this list.

How can I create a list of all combinations meeting the criteria above?

Comment: How do you define a combination? Is `[2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]` different from `[1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]`?

Comment: With the repeats allowed this seems more like `itertools.product`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will find every combination, with repeated combinations, that sum to N:

```
from itertools import product
from typing import List, Tuple
def perm_n_digit_total(n_digits, total, choices) -> List[Tuple]:
    return list(filter(
        lambda x: sum(x) == total,
        product(choices, repeat=n_digits)
    ))
```

Example:

```
perm_n_digit_total(3, 1, range(4))
Out[43]: [(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)]
```

```
perm_n_digit_total(7, 5, range(4))[::50]
Out[49]: 
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5),
 (0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0),
 (0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2),
 (0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 (2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0),
 (3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get all that sum to 5 with:

```
list(p for p in itertools.product(range(5),repeat = 7) if sum(p) == 5)
```

This yields 455 solutions.

Comment: I assume in his example, he means any digit from 0-9, not 0-4 (i.e. `range(10)`) However, I guess summing to 5, you will never need a number above 5. In which case, you should do `range(6)`

Comment: @TomMcLean But the question contained the stipulation that "Each digit can be between 0-4 only"

Comment: Ah, yep just saw.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an itertools'less recursive solution.

```py
def find_solutions(target, numbers, depth, potential_solution=[]):

    if depth == 0:
        if sum(potential_solution) == target:
            print(potential_solution)
        return

    current_sum = sum(potential_solution)

    for n in numbers:
        new_sum = current_sum + n
        if new_sum > target:
            continue
        find_solutions(target, numbers, depth - 1, potential_solution + [n])

find_solutions(target=5, numbers=[0,1,2,3,4], depth=7)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3]
...
[3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got it, you need something like this:

```
import itertools
value = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]


p = itertools.product(value, repeat=7)
for j in list(p):
  print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

As each digit can only take 5 unique values - you would require `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` -

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
zero_four = list(range(5))
for c in combinations_with_replacement(zero_four, 7):
    if sum(c) == 5:
        print(c)
```

This will give you all possible combinations that sum to `5` but not all the permutations -

**Output**

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

To get all permutations - you can use the `itertools.permutations` but since your output can have repeated elements, you will need to use a `set` to retain only unique permutations -

```py
for c in combinations_with_replacement(zero_four, 7):
    if sum(c) == 5:
        print(set(permutations(c)))
```